# "Fun" problems in Calculus III

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, big-list

What are some "fun" problems (aside from the cut and dried textbook problems) that require knowledge of Calculus III (Double/Triple integrals, partial derivatives, Green’s and Stokes’ Theorems, etc)?

Comment: Try the famous Navier-Stokes problem, you'll love it

Comment: I don't know what's "fun" to you, but I have a number of non-standard exercises (both computational and proof-oriented) in my Multivariable Mathematics book.

Comment: "Fun" is many splendored. Once  I found this interesting:  If a cylinder radius r cuts a sphere radius R centrally, after removing the central volume piece what is  left behind is a hollow cylinder of height 2h... its  volume happens to be $= \dfrac43 \pi h^3$ ( cancels out effect of R and r).